# +AND Appended to Open Search Result Source

Tags: result-source, opensearch

I have created a SharePoint search result source to query an HPECM (Trim) open search end point.
The query transform I have applied is `("{searchTerms}")({user.LoginName})`
which is then passed to the source url e.g. `<opensearchendpoint>?q={searchTerms}&pagesize={count}&start={startIndex}`.

Checking the IIS logs on the open search endpoint shows that an additional AND is being appended to the query. e.g for the query "School" the following appears in the IIS logs
q=%22School*%22+AND+%22i%3a0%23.w%7ctest%5cadmin%22+AND&pagesize=10...

Even if I change the transform to be just `"{searchTerms}"` the +AND is still appended.

How do I stop SharePoint from appending the AND to my search query?

Thanks